# I want to get the ID of the course button that is clicked and load data for that ID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I am currently using recycler view to load courses using JSON, the first course has its id in JSON that is one, and then the second, each course has its id that is stored in the db. I want that if I click the first button it should save its ID that is one to my session manager and pass it to the next activity to load its corresponding data, and when I click on the 2nd button it should load data by passing its respective ID. I have attached the onclick of my recycler view, it should get the ID of the button clicked and store it into a string that I will then store into the session manager.

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CourseAdapter mExampleAdapter;
private ArrayList<CourseItem> mExampleList;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "https://www.sniptx.com/ws/findTeacher/allCourses.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.course_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener
            .OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Item Clicked" + position , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            //handle longClick if any
        }
    }));
    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();
}
private void parseJSON() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray courseArray = obj.getJSONArray("courses");

                            for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject courseObject = courseArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String courseName = courseObject.getString("c_name");
                                String id = courseObject.getString("c_id").trim();
                                l.add(new CourseItem(courseName, id));
                            }

                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            String courseName = product.getString("c_name");
                            String id = product.getString("id").trim();

                            mExampleList.add(new CourseItem(courseName, id));
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"ID is" +id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        mExampleAdapter = new CourseAdapter(HomeActivity.this, mExampleList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass clicked I'd to another activity?

Comment: Yes you can say, i get the toast of the button clicked with their id's, they start from index 0, but the button at the first place has the id 1 in the database, check here https://www.sniptx.com/ws/findTeacher/allCourses.php first button will have id 1 while index/position in the recycler view will be 0. In the above code I've fetched the id's and now I want to pass that id to next activity/store in session manager in order to fetch its data, in simple words if first button is clicked it should send it's id that is 1 that will be passed to next activity, if the button is 2 then 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to set the data(i.e id of clicked button)as extra params of intent in first activity and get the intent extras in second activity.

```
// first activity
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);  
i.putExtra("id", value);  
startActivity(i);

// second activity
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
int id = extras.getInt("id");
```